# Redirect old website with parameters to new website with parameters under the same domain

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my old pages as the website is going through an upgrade (from coldfusion to PHP) and we want visitors in the past to still be able to access an article using the old link.

http://examplepage.com/article.cfm?ArticleID=3163

to

http://examplepage.com/articles.php?id=3163

I have been through many articles but can't find one that works the way i want it to, please advice!

Update: I found a solution, it works but is this the best way?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /article\.cfm\?ArticleID=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article\.php\?id=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ArticleID=([^&]+) 
RewriteRule ^article.cfm$ /articles.php?id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I made an update to a solution I found just after asking for help (doesn't this happens all the time?)